# Poker.SE: Card images in spoiler tag should not be revealed unless you hover over them

Tags: bug, design, spoilers

We noticed a bug on Poker.StackExchange:

Card images can be added within posts using the `<rank>&<color>;` notation e.g. `K&spades;` or `7&clubs;`.

However, if we add such card images within spoiler tags (marked by `>!`), then the text within the spoiler will be hidden, but you can still see the silhouette of the cards, which defeats the very purpose of the spoiler.

---

Here is an example:

The following text:

```
Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum 

>! Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum . I had these cards in my hand: T&diamond;9&diamond;.

Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum
```

will be rendered like this:

[image: bug-screenshot]

As you can see, the images are shown, even **if you don't** hover your mouse over the spoiler block.

Comment: You should probably post this sort of thing on Poker's meta, it is a site-specific design issue. Unless other sites have this card extension?

Comment: @Mat From what I know, only on Poker we have such card images. You may be right on posting it on Poker's meta, but I figured it wouldn't get any visibility there (it's very rarely visited).

Comment: SE employees follow tags across all metas, and site mods get notified when posts appear on their site meta. (Not a big deal anyway.)

Comment: Can you link to such a case and add a screenshot please?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I can't find a link at this moment, but I can add a screenshot :) . See my edit.

Comment: Try posting this in Poker SE Meta instead